# Design patterns for a serial of operations then commit

Tags: design-patterns

Saying I have a serial operations to update the data of a UI, like `add(), delete(), update(), clear()`.
Those operations can be combined and permuted to show specific result. And notice that after all of those operations, I have to `commit()` changes (call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in my case) to make UI update.

The following is what I design to solve this problem.

```
public UIAdapter add(Data d) {
    ...
    return adapter;
}

public UIAdapter clear() {
    ...
    return adapter;
}

// for example
public void onClick() {
    fragment.clear();
    fragment.add(new Data())
        .notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But I have to remember to 'commit changes' every time I update UI and it's somewhat tedious.

**Q:**
So I wonder if there exists better design patterns to solve this problem?

Comment: So what you want is a way to notify of a change without having to explicitly call a method? Such as a way to detect the end of the chain?

Comment: Yes, it will detect the end and call `commit()`.

Comment: This seems like a fit case for observer pattern.